# Multiple background instances of notepad.exe running

Tags: windows-11, task-manager, notepad

I just opened Task Manager to kill a process and noticed that I have 39 notepad.exe processes running - I do not use Notepad!

They appear to be background processes as in the Details tab there is no associated Username.

Where have these come from?

Windows version:

```
Edition: Windows 11 Enterprise 
Version: 23H2
OS Build: 22631.3296
Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22687.1000.0
```

notepad.exe Properties:

```
Location: c:\windows\system32
File version: 10.0.22621.3805
Date modified: 13/02/2024 18:25
```

Comment: Use Process Explorer and Auto Runs. Do the processes come back after you restart? AutoRuns will tell you why. Process Explorer can tell you the commands or processes started a process. Both of these are part of Microsoft's Sysinternals suite of tools.